# Low FPS with OpenCV VideoCapture

Tags: c++, opencv, video, opencv3.0

I am trying to display a video stream with OpenCV, but I am having horrible problems with framerate. My video source can put out a maximum of 60 fps, but I have limited it to 30. The issue is I am receiving it at about 2fps

I have simplified my program down as far as possible to make it easier to read:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{


    Mat image1;
    int k;

     const char* right_cam_gst = "nvcamerasrc sensor-id=0 ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),\
                                              width=(int)640,\
                                              height=(int)360,\
                                              format=(string)I420,\
                                              framerate=(fraction)30/1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! video/x-raw,\
                                              format=(string)I420 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,\
                                              format=(string)BGR ! appsink";



    VideoCapture cap1 = VideoCapture(right_cam_gst);




   for (;;)
    {
       cap1 >> image1;

       imshow("image1", image1);

       if(waitKey(1) == 27)
        break;
    }

}
```

This should grab and display the image as fast as the stream can allow. right?

Thanks for the help guys!

**EDIT** Looks like if I simply display an image as fast as possible, it only shows at about 1fps. This is eliminating the camera entirely.

**SYSTEM:** ubuntu on nvidia Jetson TX1

Comment: Have you tested the gstreamer pipeline in the terminal?

Comment: Yes. I get full 30 fps.

Comment: can you try to remove imshow and waitKey, add some counter and try the fps of just capturing? The aim is to find out which part is so slow, the capturing or the rendering or the waitKey (which waits AT LEAST 1ms but maybe much longer).

Comment: What is your source? How is it attached? What is your platform?

Comment: Looks like all the delay is coming from waitkey(). Doing measurements, I found it too about .75 seconds on average. Why would this be?

Comment: UPDATE: If I leave the waitkey() in and take out the inshow, the whole thing runs fairly fast. Is the problem only in showing the image?

Comment: Have you got `DISPLAY` set to an X Server that is across a slow Ethernet?

Comment: Display is indeed using an X Server, but the Ethernet isn't slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer! Looks like even though my ethernet connection was fast, it was somehow using the server for computing. (Not sure how). See this post: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1025856/very-slow-framerate-jetson-tx1-and-opencv/?offset=8

I disabled the Xserver and plugged straight in, and I got full 60 FPS.